# need to open home activity on back pressed android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a activity stack in normal case is  A -> B -> C and when i received a push notification and have implemented click_action it opens Activity C which is correct.

Now, what is need is when activity C opens from push notification after pressing back button it gets closed and whole application goes in background, but i need to navigate to Home screen (Activity A)

```
<activity
    android:name="Activity_A"
    android:exported="false"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
<activity
    android:name="Activity_B"
    android:exported="false"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
<activity
    android:name="Activity_C"
    android:exported="false"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="Activity_C" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: set onBackPress() of Activity_C and call Your home while user press back button.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because usually previous activities are saved in a stack and when user press back button the stack is called so from what i understood from your question if You want to open Home Activity through Activity C just call intent from Activity C to Home Activity by overriding the onbackpressed() method in Activity C.
Here is an Example..

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this,HomeActivity);
startActivity(homeIntent);
finish();
```

finish() is used for removing the stacked activities.

Comment: this will works in any of the case, but i need only notification case.

Answer (score 0):

you can add below line in you AndroidManifest.xml file in Activity C.

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

It will redirect you to home activity when opened from Notification and is back pressed. Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is incorrect. If the app is already open, after notification press, BACK key will traverse back from C to B to A, not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the `Notification`, add both `FLAG_ACTIVTY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVTY_CLEAR_TASK` to the `Intent` before creating the `PendingIntent` and the `Notification`.

This will cause `ActivityC` to be started in a new task, clearing out any previous activities that might have been there. Upon BACK press in `ActivityC`, the app will have no active activities, which will retun the user to the HOME screen. Starting the app again will begin with `ActivityA`.

This will have no effect on the normal progression of activities from `A->B->C`.